# How to save build configurations inside a Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is it possible to save build configurations inside a Maven project? For example in the pom?

I didn't find any way to embed build configurations inside a maven project in the maven documentation. So actually I write those builds as comments in the pom.xml.

I have multiple build configurations for each project and some have many goals with specific id and profiles. When I share the project with teammates, I also need to share how to run those complex maven builds.

Instead of writing comments inside the pom, is there a way to share the build configurations too? Maybe `.sh` files that maven will execute? But how will it works with those using Maven bundled with Eclipse?

Here is one build configuration for a project (this long, thus I need to save it as a comment in pom to remember it) :

```sh
    mvn clean -U install exec:exec@stop exec:exec@build resources:resources@copy-frontend 
    copy-rename:copy@rename-index package -Pfrontend -X
```

EDIT : I already tried maven-frontend-plugin but it didn't fit all my needs.

Comment: A usual build should be simply `mvn clean verify` or `mvn clean deploy` if need so many parameters to do your usual build your setup is wrong...why using `exec:...` `resources:...` etc. also why doing a `install` ? Why `-U`? and why using a profile `-Pfrontend` etc?

Comment: That means in the end you have not done your setup within the pom file correctly or doing some things which look from my point of view strange in particular using `exec:...` for a usual build... Please describe in detail what you are doing here... best would be a full pom file how it looks like...

Comment: It is an example for an hybrid spring-boot with spa front. The exec:exec@something executes some npm commands (serve, lint, test, etc. ...) and the profile, in this case, defines which spa framework to use (vuejs, angular, react, ...). So you have front builds (serve, stop, build, test) and back builds (install, package, test). For example `exec:exec@serve` runs `npm run serve -- --port ${ webpack.port }` according to the profile (vuejs, angular, react). For the back build configuration profile define dev, prod, shadow, test, ...

Comment: Using npm you should reconsider using [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) or alike instead of using `exec:..` ... furthermore starting a server for testing you should go via testcontainers in combination with JUnit 5 ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already gave a try to frontend-maven-plugin and I didn't find anything else than a wrapper for npm commands so I just stick to maven-exec. frontend-plugin does provide goals to simplify the javascript process but you still have custom goals outside your project.

Comment: Unfortunately haven't you posted upfront...furthermore if you have several other things you need to run you should check if there are other plugins which can handle that...or the other way put the execution of exec plugin into your pom file ...

Comment: Sorry I added this information to the post. Do you mean those executions should be included within maven default phases? If so, what phases should I use to run frontend builds?